# What is the difference between checkout and cherry-pick?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick, git-fetch

I have fetched a particular bug fix from a remote repository. Now I have two options:

1. `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
2. `git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD`

and I am not sure what is happening in both cases. I have tried the first version and it looks to me that in this way I got the changes from the remote repository into my local repository but my local changes seem to be lost (I do not see them in the code). The second option, however, seems to do what I need (I see in the code both, my changes and changes from the remote repository).

Although it looks like I got what I needed, I still want to better understand what happen in both cases.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460415/gerrit-git-pull-vs-checkout-vs-cherrypick-which-is-for-what) question and answers but I do not understand the answer because I do not know what the following phrases mean:

1. "working directory reflects X"
2. "X fetches Y"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right -  at the first command you just switched to the remote changes, while at the last you applied the remote changes on your current branch.

Besides being used for different tasks, the most significant difference is that `git-cherry-pick` changes the history of a branch, while `git checkout` is being used only to jump to a specific point in time (a specific commit) in the branch's history, without changing it.

> Switch branches or restore working tree files

`git-checkout` is used to traverse along your branch history, pointing the `HEAD` variable to a specific commit. It is also used to switch between branches

> Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits

`git-cherrypick` on the other way is used to place a single commit from another branch on top of your branch history.

For example, says you have the following branches:

```
master:
-------
commit1 1ae4d13257425e6a0d67f35fa13e9d76c4e6987b
Date:   Thu Feb 1 15:59:15 2018 +0200


commit2 cbc7776d5542f59e1e6c7c8a22add729b
Date:   Thu Feb 1 15:44:41 2018 +0200

branch:
-------
commit1 c591438ff5abbcebcbf9c06f47de7aa840
Date:   Thu Feb 1 15:45:24 2018 +0200
```

You can switch into `branch` branch using:

```
git checkout branch
```

and from `branch` you can execute the following:

```
git cherry-pick 1ae4d132
```

to play `commit1` from master on top of `commit1` from branch, making it:

```
branch:
-------
commit1 1ae4d13257425e6a0d67f35fa13e9d76c4e6987b
Date:   Thu Feb 1 15:59:15 2018 +0200

commit1 c591438ff5abbcebcbf9c06f47de7aa840
Date:   Thu Feb 1 15:45:24 2018 +0200
```

You can use traverse your history and see a single state of it using `checkout`:

```
 git checkout c591438ff5
```

This will points `HEAD` to commit `c591438ff5`, showing you the state of the branch before your cherry-picking (**but it won't change the history**)

Answer (score 1):

`cherry-pick` allows you to take one commit from the top of other branch (or from the the history of other branch) and apply it on top of you current branch.

`checkout` - in your case, it totally replace your branch with branch from remote repository. 
**UPD**. Actually your previous branch will still exist in your local git storage, but after checkout you current branch, and all your files in working directory will be replaced with that branch on what you checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Check out you will get all changes from the start while Cherry pick you just get specific changes.

Comment: what do you mean "from the start"? Start of what?

Comment: Start of your whole branch of your project.

Comment: at some point a user pulled the master and made just one change.  This change was not pushed back to master. I have pulled master later, and did my changes. Now I just want to apply the change done by another user on top of my code. So, in this context I do not see any difference between "changes form start" and "just specific change". There is just one change in question that I want to apply to my local version of the code.